# How to highlight nested structure in SourceGraph structured search?

Tags: sourcegraph, comby

I have the following SourceGraph structured search: `repo:… file:… "tls_certs" {...default = {...}...}` which correctly matches:

```
variable "tls_certs" {
  description = "…"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    …
  }
}
```

It's currently highlighting the entire `"tls_certs"` block. I would like it to highlight only the `default =` block. Assuming that's possible, how would that be done?

Comment: Hi Noel, looking into this for you.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you want to scope your search to Terraform files based on the example match provided)

Try this and see if it works for you: `:[~[\s\n]]default = {...} lang:Terraform`

It'll match a block of the form `default = {...}` that's preceded by whitespace or a newline. It's not strictly guaranteed to *only* match nested structures, but it seems to work well with the `lang:Terraform` filter.

It uses both the `...` and the `:[~regexp]` syntax of structural search. (Syntax reference docs: https://docs.sourcegraph.com/code_search/reference/structural#syntax-reference)

Example: [https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+:%5B~%5B%5Cs%5Cn%5D%5Ddefault+%3D+%7B...%7D+lang:Terraform+-repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/Wilfred/difftastic$&patternType=structural](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global+:%5B%7E%5B%5Cs%5Cn%5D%5Ddefault+%3D+%7B...%7D+lang:Terraform+-repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/Wilfred/difftastic$&patternType=structural)

Comment: The question I provided already matches fine. Currently, SourceGraph is highlighting the entire `tls_certs` block. I want it to highlight only the `default` block without matching `default` blocks not in a `tls_certs` block.

Comment: If I replace the `...default` in my query with `:[~[\s\n]]default`, SourceGraph responds with `No results matched your query`.

Comment: I see -- unfortunately it's not possible to highlight only a submatch of an overall pattern in the way you're describing (i.e. only matching `tls_certs` blocks, _and then_ only highlighting the `default` block within those blocks)